# yarn workspaces dependency install location issue

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a project that uses yarn workspaces. The structure of the project is:

```
package.json
packages
  - project A
  - project B
  - project C
```

When I run `yarn install`, the packages are installed in the project root node_modules. Recently I added another project (D) and ran `yarn install`. With project D, some of it's dependencies where installed in `projectD/node_modules` so I have some dependencies in the root and some dependencies in projectD and it's causing errors when I run the project.

Is there anyway I can "force" yarn to install all dependencies in the root node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem myself. It sounds like you have a version mismatch between a dependency of projectD, and a dependency of your other projects. The error you mention may identify what the dependency is (as it will give a 'cannot resolve module' error I'm guessing), otherwise you may find what's installed in projectD's node_modules folder will identify it.

Once identified I'd go through your yarn.lock file and work out which package/s have a dependency on the mismatching version. You may then find that updating the package that has the older version fixes your issue, or you may decide it's better to the use the `nohoist` option of workspaces

See:

https://dev.to/michalbryxi/share-common-code-with-yarn-workspaces-5g29
https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/

Answer (score -1):

Removing yarn.lock works for me.